# Error al pasar variable de JavaScript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy intentando pasar una variable de JavaScript a PHP, pero me sale un error que no entiendo porqué.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<script>
var dias = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
 var mes = '<?php echo $mes;?>';
 var dia = '<?php echo $dia;?>';
 var ano = '<?php echo $any;?>';
var fec = mes+"/"+dia+"/"+ano;
      var day = new Date(fec).getDay();
     <!---document.write(dias[day]);

     $.ajax({
    var a = document.write(dias[day]);
    url:"includes/apen_files/recarga_agenda_pordias.php",
    data:{envio:a},
    type:"post",
    success:function(a){
        document.getElementById("demo").value = a;
    }
});

</script>
```

Lo que es la parte del script sin PHP sí que funciona, pero leyendo tutoriales en internet me han dado la opción de pasarlo de JS a PHP de esa forma. Pero cuando lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, Undefined index:envio on line 38

Que es la línea del archivo PHP que carga el valor POST:

$variable = $_POST['envio'];

No sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o hay algún simple error, en ese caso pido perdón.

Comment: Solo puedes pasar variables de JavaScript a PHP de dos maneras: 1. Por medio de un formulario.  2.  Utilizando Ajax

Comment: 3. como un parámetro get: `window.location.assign("recarga_agenda_pordias.php?envio="+dias[day])`

Comment: ¿Solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

No sé exactamente que quieres hacer con este uso de Javascript, ya que normalmente se usa el Javascript para actualizar datos en un formulario o así. En cualquier caso, el error que te da es por culpa de que tus comillas no están bien, deberías usar o simples o comillas dobles de las que sacas con shift + 2 (te pasa lo mismo en la siguiente línea en PHP, a parte de olvidarte de usar el $ para la variable). Por otro lado, debes terminar la instrucción Javascript con ";" De manera que el código te quedaría así en la línea 52:

`<?php $DiaSemanaW = "<script> document.write(diasemanavar) </script>"; ?>
<?php echo "DiaSemanaW = ".$DiaSemanaW; ?>`

Obviamente, no te va a aparecer nada en el resultado porque el PHP siempre se carga antes que el Javascript (recuerda que el PHP es un lenguaje de servidor).

Comment: Vale, así si que me funciona. Entonces, como podría hacer para que esa parte se cargara a la vez que las demás partes? Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Tendrías que cargar los elementos Javascript sobre un código HTML. Si quieres hacer pruebas de introducir valores, crea una web sencilla con <HEAD><BODY> y algunos INPUT, y allí vas cargando tus datos de Javascript. Un saludo

Comment: Sí, todo esto está sobre un HTML, por eso lo preguntaba. Voy a ver algo sobre los imputs a ver que tal, no me manejo mucho en esto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene multitud de errores que pasaré a enumerar empezando por este bloque:

```
$.ajax({
  var a = document.write(dias[day]);
  url:"includes/apen_files/recarga_agenda_pordias.php",
  data:{envio:a},
  type:"post",
  success:function(a){
      document.getElementById("demo").value = a;
  }
});
```

El parámetro pasado a `.ajax()` es una clase que se define entre llaves `{ datos }` que podría inducirte erróneamente a que es similar a la definición de una función, de modo que la asignación de valor que haces (`var a = document.write(dias[day]);`) es incorrecta y te dará error.

Además, estás asignando a la variable `a` lo que devuelve `document.write` y no el día de la semana obtenido.

Para continuar, `success` a partir de jQuery 3.0 se llama `done`:

> **Deprecation Notice:** The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

En castellano:

> **Aviso de Obsolescencia:** Los métodos `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()` y `jqXHR.complete()` han sido eliminados en jQuery 3.0. Puedes usar `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()` y `jqXHR.always()` en su lugar.

Se puede usar como método, por lo que tu código quedaría:

```
var a = dias[day];
$.ajax({
  url: "includes/apen_files/recarga_agenda_pordias.php",
  data: {envio:a},
  type: "post",
}).done(function(a) {
  document.getElementById("demo").value = a;
});
```

Por otro lado, he de decirte que la única manera segura de enviar datos de PHP a javascript es mediante el uso de [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) y nunca mediante la impresión del contenido de una variable de manera directa:

```
var mes = <?= json_encode($mes) ?>;
var dia = <?= json_encode($dia) ?>;
var ano = <?= json_encode($any) ?>;
```

No es necesario que pongas entre comillas los valores porque `json_encode()` pondrá comillas si el contenido es una cadena de caracteres. En caso de valores booleanos o numéricos no las pondrá (no son necesarias).

Por último, no se recomienda llamar al constructor de [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) con una cadena de fecha localizada. Es recomendable usar el contructor en el que se usan como parámetros el día, mes y año:

```
var day = new Date(
  <?= json_encode($any) ?>,
  <?= json_encode($mes) ?>,
  <?= json_encode($dia) ?>
).getDay();
```

---

Este es el código que he usado para reproducir tu problema y arreglarlo:

**nuevo.php**

```
<?php
/* El 28 de febrero de 2018 fue miércoles */
$mes = 02;
$dia = 28;
$any = 2018
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Título de ejemplo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    var dias = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];
    var day = new Date(
        <?= json_encode($any) ?>,
        <?= json_encode($mes) ?>,
        <?= json_encode($dia) ?>
    ).getDay();
    console.log('Enviando el valor', dias[day]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'receptor.php',
        data: {
            envio: dias[day],
        },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(a) {
        console.log(a);
        document.getElementById("demo").value = a;
    });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="demo" value="Valor inicial" size="40" />
</body>

</html>
```

**receptor.php**

```
<?php
/* Indicamos que el valor devuelto será JSON codificado en UTF-8 */
header('Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
/* Obtenemos el valor enviado por XHR */
if (isset($_POST['envio'])) {
  $variable = $_POST['envio'];
} else {
  $variable = '(no se recibieron datos por POST)';
}
/* Devolvemos una cadena montada con dicho valor */
echo json_encode("Hemos recibido: $variable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues que yo sepa que para interactuar javascript o jquery con php se hace a través de ajax y lo envías ya sea por método POST o GET.

```
  $.ajax({
        var a = "Tu valor";
        url:"includes/controler.php",
        data:{eliminarContact:a},
        type:"post",
        success:function(a){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Pero podría usar ajax para cargar ese valor en la misma página?

Comment: Claro, de hecho se usa para no recargar la pagina, ya dependiendo del valor que te regrese lo asignas a tu selector, ejemplo tienes un <p id="myselector"></p>

document.getElementById(“myselector”).value = “Tu Valor”;

Comment: Lo estoy intentando así:
` $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
     var diasemanavar = document.write(dias[day]);
                    url: 'includes/apen_files/recarga_agenda_pordias.php',
                    data: {
                     diasemanavar: nombresem},
                    success:function(diasemanavar){
            location.reload();
        }
              }); `

Pero me dice undefined index nombresem , lo he puesto mal?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es mandar tus datos a tu codigo php.

```
$.ajax({
    var a = document.write(dias[day]);
    url:"includes/apen_files/recarga_agenda_pordias.php",
    data:{envio:a},
    type:"post",
    success:function(a){
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Después en tu archivo php haces la función que deseas hacer.

```
if(isset($_POST['envio'])){
//Aqui obtienes la variable $_POST[envio] y haces las funciones que vayas a hacer luego la imprimes
echo $variable;
}
```

y enla ultima parte del ajax lo asignas a tu elemento a través del ID o clase o por selector.

```
success:function(a){
        document.getElementById(“myselector”).value = a;
    }
```

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el error de Undefined index: envio on line 38, que es la de:
`$variable = $_POST['envio'];` , no lo entiendo porque lo he puesto como tú, aplicando el ID y me sigue saliendo. Te dejo mi código JS en la pregunta a ver si hay algún error. Gracias por tu ayuda